# My modal trigger renders all modals instead of specific modals by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an antd table with a view more icon that pops up a modal. The icon is supposed to render each modal according to the id and details of that particular row on the table but currently, each of the icons simply renders all the modals on top of each other

```
const ViewUpload = props => {
    const { visible, onCancel, data, onOk } = props;

    return (
        <>
            {
                data.map(({ description, id, url, title }) => (
                    <Modal
                        key={id}
                        visible={visible}
                        closable={false}
                        onCancel={onCancel}
                        title={title}
                        onOk={onOk}
                    >
                        <Card
                            cover={(
                                <video className="uploaded-video" controls>
                                    <source src={url} />
                                    <track src="name" kind="captions" />
                                </video>
                                )}
                        >
                            <Meta title={title} description={description} />
                        </Card>
                    </Modal>
                ))
            }
        </>
    );
};
```

Then inside the component that renders the modal I have

```
<ViewUpload
    visible={preview}
    onCancel={() => setPreview(false)}
    data={videos}
    onOk={() => setPreview(false)}
/>
```

The button that triggers the modal inside this component

```
<Tooltip placement="top" title="View details">
    <Button
        onClick={() => setPreview(true)}
        type="link"
        icon="eye"
    />
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, it seems that the view more button sets 'preview' state 'true'
and all modals 'visible' props are equal to the value of the 'preview' state cause you passed the 'preview 'state as 'visible' prop to the Viewupload.
so when you click on the view more button, it sets the 'preview' state true and pass it down to the ViewUpload component, and all modals are listening to that state so the became visible!

so if you want the modal listen to the specific button,
the first way is to take modals out of the viewUpload component and data loop
or the second way is pass the selected modal id to viewUpload

I don't know that the show more button has access to the id of the clicked row
but if it's in a loop do this changes

```
<Button
  onClick={() => setSelectedModal(modal.id)}
  type="link"
  icon="eye"
/>
```

so the button will put modal id in the state called 'selectedModal'

then pass it down like this

```
<ViewUpload
  selectedModal={selectedModal}
  onCancel={() => setSelectedModal(null)}
  data={videos}
  onOk={() => setSelectedModal(null)}
/>
```

and final change in the ViewUpload component

```
// some codes
const { selectedModal, onCancel, data, onOk } = props;
// some other codes
<Modal
   key={id}
   visible={selectedModal === id}
   closable={false}
   onCancel={onCancel}
   title={title}
   onOk={onOk}
>
```